# how to Filter the Search by categories in Magento at the search result

Tags: magento-1.7, catalogsearch, search

any one can please help , our Magento store is not good with search and i was wondering if there is any way to put categories on the search result page on right side so the buyer can filter what they after.

Thanks in advacne

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible natively, as products can belong to multiple categories. It is possible however to code a custom filter. You will want to look at example in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/`, and you will need to add your filter to the list.